# MySQL Subquery calculations

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this mysql query and when I search for a user and he has one login(start - end) it shows the total on the next row alright but if the user has more than one login(start - end) it doesnt show the total on the next row....

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name
   , start.timestamp start
   , end.timestamp end
   , timediff(end.timestamp, start.timestamp) duration 
FROM user u
   , user_group ug
   , (
      select *
         , (
            select event_id
            from event L2 
            where L2.timestamp > L1.timestamp
               and L2.user_bannerid = L1.user_bannerid
            order by timestamp limit 1  
           ) stop_id
      From event L1
     ) start
join event end on end.event_id = start.stop_id
where start.status = 'In'
   and end.status='Out'
   and u.user_bannerid = start.user_bannerid
   and ug.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid
   and ug.group_id = start.group_id 

UNION

SELECT null, null, null, CAST(sum(duration) as Time)
FROM
(
   SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name
      , start.timestamp start
      , end.timestamp end
      , timediff(end.timestamp, start.timestamp) duration 
   from user u
      , user_group ug
      , (
         select *
         , (
            select event_id
            from event L2
            where L2.timestamp > L1.timestamp
               and L2.user_bannerid = L1.user_bannerid
            order by timestamp
            limit 1
           ) stop_id
         from event L1
        ) start
   join event end on end.event_id = start.stop_id
   where start.status = 'In'
      and end.status = 'Out'
   and u.user_bannerid = start.user_bannerid
   and ug.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid
      and ug.group_id = start.group_id 
) total
```

it show the total alright when the user has only one login

```
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Name   | start               | end                 | duration      |    
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| User   | 2011-11-24 02:12:05 | 2011-11-24 02:12:20 | 00:00:15      |       
|        |                     |                     | 00:00:15      |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

But when the user has more than one login, it doesnt show the total hours,

```
    +----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
    | Name   | start               | end                 | duration      |    
    +----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
    | User   | 2011-11-24 02:12:05 | 2011-11-24 02:12:20 | 00:00:15      |       
    | User   | 2011-11-28 21:46:54 | 2011-11-28 21:53:01 | 00:06:17      |
    |        |                     |                     |               |
    +----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

im guessing it has to do with the Limits, but if i change the limit to more than 1 i get "the error no 1242 Subquery returns more than one row."  can someone please help me rephrase the query to show total hours no matter how many logins they have?

Edit:

still having problems with this so i came up with a new query but then i keep getting null instead of the total.
any idea why this is so?

```
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Name   | start               | end                 | duration      |    
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| User   | 2011-11-24 02:12:05 | 2011-11-24 02:12:20 | 00:00:15      |       
| User   | 2011-11-28 21:46:54 | 2011-11-28 21:53:01 | 00:06:17      |
| User   | 2011-11-28 21:46:54 | 2011-11-28 21:53:01 | null          |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+

SELECT
    CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name,
    start.timestamp AS start,
    end.timestamp AS end,
    TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(end.timestamp, start.timestamp))) AS duration 
FROM user AS u
    INNER JOIN user_group AS ug ON u.user_bannerid = ug.user_bannerid
    INNER JOIN event AS start ON start.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid AND start.status='In' AND start.group_id = ug.group_id
    INNER JOIN event AS end ON end.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid AND end.status='Out' AND start.event_id < end.event_id 
GROUP BY start.event_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Where `00:00:32` came from in the first "alright" result?

Comment: sorry typo... its the total  00:00:15

Comment: We see the results... Can you post some raw data that is the basis of this query result... that would better help, even if just showing bogus user name, but ID, status, group, timestamp entries.  Additionally, is it ever POSSIBLE for a person to have two LOG "IN" entries in a row without the corresponding Log "OUT" between them.

Comment: Hey i updated it... also if a user logs in twice before logging out,  the query will take only the first login and match it with the logout and subtract the difference to get how long you were logged in. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to add a stop_id to the event table, then when the user logs out, update the In event with the record id from the Out event.

For existing records, you could write a query to update the records based on your logic in the question.

Once you do this, since you have a stop_id in the event table, getting the start and stop time is a relatively trivial query.

Leaving the user information out for now, this is all you need to get the details:

```
SELECT start.timestamp start ,
       end.timestamp end ,
       timediff(end.timestamp, start.timestamp) duration 
  FROM event start join event end on end.event_id = start.stop_id
```

You don't need to test the start or stop status because presumably only those events with a status of `In` will have a `stop_id` and the inner join (assuming that's what join does in mysql) prevents `Out` records from being included at the top level.