# VB.net block double entry

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is the event table that records all the status(IN/OUT):

```
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Event_ID | User_BannerID  | Group_ID | Timestamp | Status | Creator|
+----------+----------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|          |                |          |           |        |        |
|          |                |          |           |        |        |
+----------+----------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

So am making a sign in-out program using vb.net and mysql. i was wondering if theres a code i can put in somewhere that will be like if a user opens the application he/she must signin before they can signout and if they open the application and they've already signed in, they cant signin again they must signout before they can sign out again.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class frmMain
    Private myConnString As String
    Private myUserID As String

    Public WriteOnly Property connectionString() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myConnString = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property UserID() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myUserID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub refreshStatus(ByRef statusView As DataGridView)
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As String


        SQL = "SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name, ug.group_name AS Class, DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%b %d %Y - %r')AS DateTime, e.status AS Status " _
             & "FROM event e, user u, user_group ug " _
             & "WHERE(e.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid) " _
             & "AND e.group_id = ug.group_id " _
             & "AND ug.user_bannerid = ?userID " _
             & "AND event_id IN " _
             & "( " _
             & "Select MAX(e.event_id) " _
             & "FROM event e " _
             & "GROUP BY e.user_bannerid " _
             & ") " _
             & "ORDER BY datetime"



        conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("?userID", myUserID)

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(myData)

                dgvStatus.DataSource = myData
                dgvStatus.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("There was an error reading from the database: " & myerror.Message)
                End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to the database: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
            End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cboStatus.Items.Add("In")
        cboStatus.Items.Add("Out")
        cboStatus.SelectedIndex = 0

        dgvStatus.ReadOnly = True
        refreshStatus(dgvStatus)

        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As String


        SQL = "SELECT ug.group_id, ug.group_name " _
         & "FROM attendance.user_group ug " _
         & "WHERE user_bannerid = ?userID and level_id is NULL "

        conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("?userID", myUserID)


                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(myData)

                cboClass.DataSource = myData
                cboClass.DisplayMember = "group_name"
                cboClass.ValueMember = "group_id"
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("There was an error reading from the database: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to the database: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand

        conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO event(user_bannerid, group_id, timestamp, status, creator)" _
         & "VALUES(?UserID, ?GroupID, NOW(), ?Status, ?Creator)"

        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?UserID", myUserID)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?GroupID", cboClass.SelectedValue)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Status", cboStatus.SelectedItem)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Creator", myUserID)

        Try
            conn.Open()
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Status Successfully Updated")
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("There was an error updating the database: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
        refreshStatus(dgvStatus)
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
        Dim oForm As frmLogin
        oForm = New frmLogin()
        frmLogin.Show()
        oForm = Nothing
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        Dim oForm As frmLogin
        oForm = New frmLogin()
        frmLogin.Show()
        oForm = Nothing
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just automatically sign the user out if they are already signed in before signing them in again? You can just tell them (through a messagebox or something) that they have been automatically signed out of their previous session if you discover that they were previously signed in.

**Update**

In reviewing your question and code, I think that you are making life far too difficult for yourself by relying on the activity log to provide the user status. The activity log should just be for recording discrete activities, not for determining the user's status.

What I recommend is that you add a status field to the user table. This will always store the user's current status, in or out.

When the user opens your application, you will have a simple check: what is the user's status? If the user is logged in, show the user a Log Out button. If the user is not logged in show them a Log Out button. Don't let them choose from the dropdown what their status is because I can guarantee they will mess something up.

If the user is logged in, but wants to log in again, they can press the log out button. You will update the user table with their new status and record the activity, then disable the Log Out button and enable the Log In button. When they press the Log In button, you will update the user status and record the new activity.

As an option, if the user is currently logged in when they start the app, you can show them (from the activity log or as a separate field in the user record) the last time they logged in so they are not confused about why they are being presented with the logout button.

**Update with specific code**

```
Private Const STATUS_IN As String = "In"
Private Const STATUS_OUT As String = "Out"

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Disable the buttons to start
    btnLogin.Enabled = False
    btnLogout.Enabled = False

    Dim sCurrentStatus As String

    ' Get the user's current status
    sCurrentStatus = GetUserStatus()

    ' And update the buttons based on this status change
    Call UpdateButtonsForStatusChange(sCurrentStatus)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateButtonsForStatusChange(sStatus As String)

    Dim fLoggedIn As Boolean

    ' Determine whether or not the user is logged in based on the status
    fLoggedIn = sStatus.Equals(STATUS_IN, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

    ' If the user is NOT logged in, enable the login button
    btnLogin.Enabled = Not fLoggedIn
    ' If the user IS logged in, enable the logout button
    btnLogout.Enabled = fLoggedIn

End Sub

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    ' Indicate that the user is logging in
    Call HandleButtonClick(STATUS_IN)
End Sub

Private Sub btnLogout_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogout.Click
    ' Indicate that the user is logging out
    Call HandleButtonClick(STATUS_OUT)
End Sub

Private Sub HandleButtonClick(sNewStatus As String)

    ' Update the database with the user's new status
    Call UpdateUserStatus(sNewStatus)
    ' And update the buttons based on this status change
    Call UpdateButtonsForStatusChange(sNewStatus)

End Sub

Private Function GetUserStatus() As String

    ' ToDo: Add your code to get the user's current status here

End Function

Private Sub UpdateUserStatus(sNewStatus As String)

    ' ToDo: Add your code to save the user's current status here

End Sub
```

Comment: There should be a KISS badge on SO.

Comment: thanks this is really a great idea but can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with additional information on how I think you should proceed.

Comment: i get everything now but if you dont mind can you show me an example of how to do the check and how to display a different button based on their status?

Comment: @user1012135: Ok, I have added the framework to the answer. You need to add two buttons to the form, btnLogin and btnLogout along with the rest of your logic and the database interaction.

Comment: Hey can you check to see if you can help me on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318369/mysql-subquery-calculations

Its based on the answer i got from this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306032/calculate-the-total-time-duration-on-last-row-in-mysql

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't like competent_tech's answer.
Ask yourself these questions.

How if you are out, but haven't signed out do you sign out?

How if you haven't signed in can you be in to sign out?

In either situation "sumfin had gone rong".

For missing signout.

Sign out then sign in, your users will find that immensely irritating if you make them jump through hoops, when you could have just signed them out and gone from there.

The other is a hole in your code somewhere, how often it happens would be the real concern, hole in the close logic, perhaps some sort of unhandled exeception. There are situation where you can never guarantee your code will close properly, even if you refused to close because you couldn't successfully sign out, the user can still mess you up. Waste of effort.